# What spells didn't exist in 3.5 but exist in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, dnd-3.5e, edition-comparison

What are the spells that exist in the Player's Handbook of D&D 5e but that didn't exist in D&D 3.5 core books?

I'm not so much interested in renamed/merged spells but in spells with wholly new effects, including those spells that may share a name with an old spell but also have wholly new effects. I was wondering whether any new interesting effects were invented since 3rd edition when searching for new spells to houserule into a 3rd edition game.

Comment: This really isn’t that hard. There are only so many spells in 5e’s _Player’s Handbook_, and most of them are D&D classics that any veteran player will immediately recognize, leaving a much smaller number to double-check. 3.5e, of course, has a ton of books, but there are also excellent resources out there for searching them. Just plugging in the spells one needs to double-check would yield an answer. Tedious, but not too much trouble. And I, for one, agree it would be interesting. If you don’t, just move on, or downvote if you insist. This question has no problems with respect to the rules.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of the 361 spells present in the 5e Player's Handbook, 62 are new and not present in 3.5.

I didn't count spell renames (Minor Image-> Minor Illusion) or spell merging/splitting (such as the Cure Wounds line) as different spells.

These are the new spells:

- Arcane Gate
- Armor of Agathys
- Arms of Hadar
- Aura of Life
- Aura of Purity
- Aura of Vitality
- Banishing Smite
- Beacon of Hope
- Beast Sense
- Blade Ward
- Blinding Smite
- Branding Smite
- Chromatic Orb
- Circle of Power
- Compelled Duel
- Compulsion
- Conjure Barrage
- Conjure Volley
- Cordon of Arrows
- Crown of Madness
- Crusader's Mantle
- Destructive Smite
- Dissonant Whispers
- Druidcraft
- Elemental Weapon
- Enhance Ability
- Ensnaring Strike
- Feign Death
- Find Familiar
- Fire Bolt
- Friends
- Giant Insect
- Grasping Vines
- Guardians of Faith
- Guiding Bolt
- Hail of Thorns
- Healing Word
- Hellish Rebuke
- Hex
- Hunger of Hadar
- Hunter's Mark
- Lightning Arrow
- Mass Healing Ward
- Misty Step
- Moonbeam
- Phantasmal Force
- Poison Spray
- Power Word Heal
- Prayer of Healing
- Sacred Flame
- Searing Flame
- Spare the Dying
- Staggering Smite
- Swift Quiver
- Thaumaturgy
- Thorn Whip
- Thunderous Smite
- Thunderwave
- Vicious Mockery
- Warding Bond
- Witch Bolt
- Wrathful Smite

For completeness, the renamed spells that I didn't consider as new are:

- *antipathy* and *sympathy* to *antipathy/sympathy*
- *clairaudience/clairvoyance* to *clairvoyance*
- *summon nature's ally* to various *conjure X* spells
- *create water* to *create or destroy water*
- *major creation* to *creation*
- *cure light wounds* et al. to *cure wounds*
- *detect evil* and *detect good* to *detect evil and good*
- *detect poison* to *detect poison and disease*
- *dispel evil* and *dispel good* to *dispel evil and good*
- *holy word* to *divine word*
- *phantom steed* to *find steed*
- *inflict light wounds* et al. to *inflict wounds*
- *detect animals or plants* to *locate animals or plants*
- *magic circle against alignment* to *magic circle*
- *minor image* to *minor illusion*
- *programmed image* to *programmed illusion*
- *protection from evil* and *protection from good* to *protection from evil and good*
- *neutralize poison* to *protection from poison*
- *ray of sickening* to *ray of sickness*
- *telepathic bond* to *telepathy*

Comment: 3.5e has a _cloud of daggers_, in _Player’s Handbook II_ I believe. _Eldritch blast_ also existed, in fact debuted, in 3.5e’s _Complete Arcane_, where it was an “invocation,” but 3.5e’s invocations were very much like 5e’s cantrips: _eldritch blast_ itself has barely changed at all except in some details of the progression. And the various _conjure_ spells (aside from _barrage_ and _volley_) are just the various options from 3.5e’s _summon nature’s ally_ spells split up into separate spells. Pretty sure _crown of madness_ also existed in 3.5e, and _animal friendship_ in 3e.

Comment: Thanks - I edited in all the changes, except I couldn't find *crown of madness* in the SRD.

Comment: @KRyan Fortunately, the question's only concerned with the *3.5* core books, making it so we don't have point out that, for example, *Tome & Blood* includes the *feign death* spell (89). (If the answer wants to go beyond the core books, though, that's cool.)

Comment: I would consider divine word to be an equivalent spell to *holy word* from 3.5e (and a possible merge with *blasphemy)*. Also note 'minot image' typo in second line.

Comment: 5e has both *phantom steed* and *find steed* as different distinct spells, so although I don't know that much about 3.5e *phantom steed to find steed* seems suspicious. Same with *telepathic bond* and *telepathy*

Comment: @SilentAxe is correct, *find steed* and *phantom steed* are not remotely similar. The 5e *find steed* spell is actually a replacement for the 3.5e paladin’s special mount class feature (just as *find familiar* replaces the familiar class feature of 3.5e sorcerers and wizards).